# linux threading, sleep in main

Tags: linux, multithreading, loops, sleep, program-entry-point

My program has a number of threads, the main loop has no function. I used to code the main loop as while(1){sleep(1);}.

I now ask myself but can't tell for sure if performance-wise an empty main loop (while(1){}) is better than having sleep(1) or vice versa, or the same???

I thought the scheduler checks every tasks in every scheduling cycle to see if they need to be woken up, which does:

- when main is an empty while loop: wake up to do nothing
- when main is a sleeping loop: the wake up time stamp is checked/recalculated, if needs to be woken up, then wake up to do nothing

Make any differences?

Comment: I would use `pause()` instead of `sleep(1)`. It is like `sleep()` but with an infinite timeout. It will wake less frequently (only on signals) so it will consume less resources.

Answer (score 2):

there is much difference.
sleep(1) version is much better than empty while(1){}.

sleep(1) let system kernel check time , when the time alarm reach ,it will run next step. So it just cost a little resource.

but the while(1){} is different, it will  run the statement "while(1)" all the time, it will cost a lot of CPU resource(all the resource it can get).

you can use `top` command to check resource usage, you will find sleep(1) version use only a little resource while "while(1){}" use 100% CPU (of a Cpu core/thread)

Answer (score 1):

When you use threading, the best option would probably be to have no loop in the main thread but the `join` operation, which waits for the other threads to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about the empty while loop, which costs all remaining CPU as peter__barnes mentioned. My real program had this in main(): while(someCondition){//empty loop}. And the someCondition() had some signal waiting inside. I just thought about comparing an empty loop in main() with the other programs where I had while(1){sleep(1);} in main(). But it was not an empty loop to start with. So my question was wrong, but anyway, it has opened to me things I didn't know before, and the follow-up question:

In case my program is a daemon which will never exit, is pause() or join() in main() better?